# Using articles in titles

Tags: sentence-construction, articles

I want to write a title for an article, it is

> On-line system for detecting defects in traveling grate based on machine vision

I don't know if I should use articles like (An online system) or (a/the traveling grate) or not?

I feel if I use article it miss the generality, on the other hand I know countable objects need an article. Are titles exception, because I feel I have seen such titles?

Comment: Articles are often omitted in newspapers, but in other cases you shouldn't omit them.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would look at other similar works from your publication or field. If you are attempting to publish this article, e.g. in a journal, that journal will most likely have a style guide you should follow. Dropping the first article sounds stilted, but is also common in some formats like abstracts in some science journals. I would definitely include the "a" before "traveling gate", however.

Your concern about missing the general case is solved by using the indefinite articles "a" and "an" rather than the definite "the".